# Odoo high scale deployment

Tags: django, rest, deployment, django-rest-framework, odoo

I am developing a Django REST API with Odoo at the backend. This API will be used by more than 1000 users concurrently and I do not have any clue as to how I can deploy my API and Odoo for such high incoming traffic. The API has endpoints to perform CRUD operations on Odoo for specific models through XMLRPC-Lib.

I know that Odoo has multi process mode wherein we can use worked based on a formula. But what should be the server capacity in order to handle these many users. And what kind load balancers are required?

Also how do I deploy Django REST Framework to handle these many requests.

If there is no specific answer to this question then what are the parameter do i have to look into, in order decide on the server configuration, load balancers, number of Odoo instances and Django Instances

Thanx in adnvace
Regards
Shivam Goyal

Answer (score 2):

The basics are:

To have Odoo run in multiworker mode, just set the number of workers using the `--workers` option ([docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/cmdline.html)).

You should also use a reverse proxy service upfront Odoo to implement SSL, cache static assets (reducing the load on Odoo). Nginx is a popular choice here, and it also supports basic load balancing strategies, through `upstream` definitons.

It sounds like you're not so experienced with Odoo deployments. IMO for that kind of workload volumw it would be worth asking for professional help on that topic.

*PS: Why the extra Django layer if you can build them directly with Odoo web [controllers](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/http.html)?*

Comment: We are building some kind of a marketplace. That way our website will be hosted on Django. Also we do not want to expose our Odoo directly to the user. Presence of Django will also avoid lots of request that may not be valid and save Odoo load on Odoo server for wrong request

Comment: Fair enough, that's a valid design choice.